# Pages from a known textbook on Euclidean geometry?

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry, teaching

Do you recall having seen the attached pages in a textbook once? If so, would you be so kind as to share its bibliographic record (or the main items in it) with me below?

A teacher provided us xerox copies of these exercises *maaany* years ago, but I did not have the presence of mind at the moment to ask him where he had gotten them from.

Let me thank you in advance for your attention and for allowing me to pose this question in spite of the fact that it may be a wee bit borderline for the site...

[image] [image]

Comment: A German course assistant of mine used this same set of problems in a geometry course I taught in Summer 2017.  I will try to reach out to her and see if she knows the source.

Comment: She responded to me *very* quickly.  Although we traced the chain of custody back two levels, the trail seems to bottom out there.  The person from whom she got them said "At one time I asked a friend in the math coaching biz who was from Germany if he recognized them, and he said 'Yeah, looks like basically every math textbook I had in school.'"

Comment: Indeed, that was quick... Thanks a bunch for your cooperation!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These are pages 4 and 5 from Paul Eigenmann, *Geometrische Denkaufgaben,* Klett+Balmer, Zug, 1982 (ISBN 3-264-72231-3).

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit unsure about the purpose of the question: precisely this textbook or an equivalent one? For what it's worth, [Mathematik für Mittelschulen: Geometrie](https://www.the-ride-goes-wild.ch/simi/Schule/Frommenwiler/Frommenwiler.pdf) by Frommenwilder and Studer has very similar images:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Mr. Beenakker. I am mainly interested in determining the provenance of the very pages I have uploaded but the exercises in this other book you have encountered certainly resemble the ones handed in to us back in the day. Seems like the acquaintance of the acquaintance of @LSpice's assistant  was not kidding when he said that the pages resemble a great deal those "in every math textbook [he/she] had in school".